# Android: how to hide UI view from showing EditText lines being nulled before Activity finish();?

Tags: android, view, null, settext

I have five EditText lines with data that is saved in a database.  Thereafter, how do I clear the five EditText lines and make them null and then close my Activity without the user seeing the View updating to show the lines being cleared?

```
Activity code 

public class AddorUpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Save data to database
    ...
    // Return to MainActivity
    Intent returnMain = new Intent(AddorUpdateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(returnMain); 
    // Clear the EditText lines before finishing.
    cEditText.setText(null); dEditText.setText(null); eEditText.setText(null);
    fEditText.setText(null); gEditText.setText(null);
    // Close the EditActivity.
    finish();



}
```

Comment: Try overwriting the onDestroy() function

Comment: All views in activity will destroy, so it is meaningless to do anything to editText after `finish()`

Comment: @L2_Paver So move the setText(null) code into onDestroy because that will be run after the Activity's view has finished?

Comment: yes, I also realize what @huang12345 says make sense.

Comment: @huang 12345 I don't have any code above that comes after finish().  I'm trying to somehow close the current Activity view so the user doesn't see the EditText lines being cleared (set to "null").  Any ideas?

Comment: @AJW Users won't see anything if activity finish()

Comment: huang 12345 I understand that.  I'm trying to find a way to clear the EditTexts after the view is removed so the user does not notice the 5 lines being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

```
cEditText.setText(null); dEditText.setText(null); eEditText.setText(null); fEditText.setText(null); gEditText.setText(null);
```

Remove all of the above lines from your code. You should be fine.

When activity is destroyed all of its views are also destroyed. However, when you try to create a new instance of same type of view as the one that's destroyed, there's a possibility that your views might get restored automatically (assuming you have not set setRetainInstance to false and assigned IDs to your views)

If you don't want that simply add setRetainInstance = false in your xml and remove all above code. This way your views will not be restored. However, be careful with this approach as device rotation WILL lead to data loss in your views. In such cases you should either save data in view models or implement onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods in your activity.